# Having trouble getting data with this inner join ( MYSQL / PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables that I am trying to return a column from and it's making me cry why it's not working:

```
$projectId = 54971033
$id = 53189015
```

[image]

```
        SELECT     
            iR.author,
            i.dateCreated,
            i.lastModified,
            i.value,
            u.username
        FROM
            informationRelationships iR
        INNER JOIN
            information i ON
            iR.linkId = i.id
        INNER JOIN
            users u ON
            iR.author = u.id    
        WHERE
            iR.contactRef = '$id' AND
            iR.projectRef = '$projectId' AND
            iR.type = 'Project'
```

Any ideas why it's returning nothing?

Comment: Could you give a dump of the generated query, just to rule out variable issues?

Comment: Try your query without the filter.

Comment: Any chance of an SQL fiddle for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `author` is zero so try using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT     
    iR.author,
    i.dateCreated,
    i.lastModified,
    i.value,
    u.username
FROM
    informationRelationships iR
LEFT JOIN
    information i ON
    iR.linkId = i.id
LEFT JOIN
    users u ON
    iR.author = u.id    
WHERE
    iR.contactRef = '$id' AND
    iR.projectRef = '$projectId' AND
    iR.type = 'Project'
```

Comment: One issue, It's not returning the username of the user "admin". "u.username" I assume it is because the users join is failing due to the value being 0. I'm really unsure of how to make it compare the 0

Comment: that is correct ... since the `author` is zero there's no match found in `users` table... what you can do is update the `author` field to `1`

Comment: Makes sense. I've made a boo boo. Thanks for the help